# Counting number of xml tags in python using xml.dom.minidom

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

My XML file test.xml contains the following tags

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<AppName>
    <author>Subho Halder</author>
    <description> Description</description>
    <date>2012-11-06</date>
        <out>Output 1</out>
        <out>Output 2</out>
        <out>Output 3</out>
</AppName>
```

I want to count the number of times the `<out>` tag has occured

This is my python code so far which I have written:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
file = open('test.xml','r')
data = file.read()
file.close()
dom = parseString(data)
if (len(dom.getElementsByTagName('author'))!=0):
    xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('author')[0].toxml()
    author = xmlTag.replace('<author>','').replace('</author>','')
    print author
```

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Is it just not ``len(dom.getElementsByTagName('out'))`` you make no mention of ``out`` in your code only ``author``

Comment: ahhh, I am just a beginner ! thanks for the answer.

Comment: Just read up on what ``dom.getElementsByTagName('out')`` is doing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [`len(dom.getElementsByTagName('out'))`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#document-objects)

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
file = open('test.xml','r')
data = file.read()
file.close()
dom = parseString(data)
print len(dom.getElementsByTagName('out'))
```

gives

```
3
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using lxml

```
import lxml.etree
doc = lxml.etree.parse(test.xml)
count = doc.xpath('count(//out)')
```

You can look up more information on XPATH [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pylxml/web/xpath.html).

Comment: lxml needs dependency to be installed, it doesn't work out of box !

Comment: @SunnyRockzzs its fast and better for you to use it in the long run, especially if things get more complex. Assuming you are using Ubuntu, `apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev` should install the dependencies.

Comment: I must say ``lxml`` is great and given the choice I'd suggest it each and every time but OP was using ``xml.dom.minidom``.

Comment: i am creating a product, which just needs the end user to install python, if i use lxml, it becomes one more perquisite to install

Comment: @SunnyRockzzs I'm sure there are adequate solutions for installing Python and your dependencies but that's only worth it if ``lxml`` buys you speed of execution and better Xml apis. I once installed it locally with my application because of I couldn't enforce multiple users to have to install my code + dependecies.

Answer (score 2):

If you want you can also use [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). With the function below you will get a dictionary with the tag names as the key and number of times this tag is encountered in you XML file.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import Counter

def count_tags(filename):
        my_tags = []
        for event, element in ET.iterparse(filename):
            my_tags.append(element.tag)
        my_keys = Counter(my_tags).keys()
        my_values = Counter(my_tags).values()
        my_dict = dict(zip(my_keys, my_values))
        return my_dict
```